# Let $(X,\mathcal M)$ be a measurable space and $\nu$ a signed measure on it. Show $|\nu|$ is the smallest measure such that...

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal M)$ be a measurable space and $\nu$ a signed measure on it. Show that the smallest positive measure $\mu$ such that $$-\mu(E) \le \nu(E) \le \mu(E)$$
for every $E \in \mathcal M$ is $\mu=|\nu|$.

I know $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ are both non-negative measures such that $\nu=\nu^+-\nu^-$, and $|\nu|=\nu^++\nu^-$ (the last is called a total variation measure). But, I am unsure on how to show $-|\nu|(E) \le \nu(E) \le |\nu|(E)$. I have reviewed similar questions on this site, but are still unsure of how get these particular inequalities.

Comment: $\nu^+$ and $\nu^-$ are both positive measures, so $\nu(E) = \nu^+(E)-\nu^-(E)\le\nu^+(E)+\nu^-(E) = |\nu|(E)$. The other inequality is likewise trivial.

Comment: Thank you. So do I simply begin with definition of $|\nu|$ and arise at these inequalities, and this shows $|\nu|$ is the smallest measure? Or, is there more to it that I am overlooking (I just seen your answer posted below - Thank you)

Comment: Please place your questions under the answer, if you have any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $-|\nu|\le\nu\le|\nu|$ follows easily as shown in the comments. Now, let $\mu$ be a measure with $-\mu\le\nu\le\mu$, i.e., $|\nu(E)|\le\mu(E)$ for all $E\in\mathcal M$. Then
\begin{align}
|\nu|(E)
&= \sup\left\{\sum_n|\nu(E_n)| : E = \bigcup_nE_n\,\text{(disjoint)}\right\}\\
&\le \sup\left\{\sum_n\mu(E_n) : E = \bigcup_nE_n\,\text{(disjoint)}\right\}\\
&= \mu(E).
\end{align}